# ns2 installation error on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ns2

I try to install ns-2.35 all-in-one package on my Ubuntu 12.10

I type "./configure" and then "make" in folder "tcl-8.5.10" and folder "tk8.5.10"

There is no make error.

But when I enter folder otcl-1.14 and type "./configure" it shows an error:

```
dartkouth@dartkouth-P8010:/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl$ sudo ./configure
No .configure file found in current directory
Continuing with default options...
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... yes
checking for dcgettext in -lintl... no
checking for getnodebyname in -ldnet_stub... no
checking that g++ can handle -O2... no
checking standard STL is available... no
./configure: line 4803: tclsh: command not found
checking for tcl.h... -I../include
checking for tclInt.h... -I../include
checking for libtcl... no
checking for init.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5
checking for http.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5/http1.0
checking Tcl http.tcl library... yes
checking for tclsh... no
checking for tclsh... no
checking for tclsh... no
checking for tclsh8.4... no
configure: error: Installation of tcl seems incomplete or can't be found automatically.
Please correct the problem by telling configure where tcl is
using the argument --with-tcl=/path/to/package
(perhaps after installing it),
or the package is not required, disable it with --with-tcl=no.
dartkouth@dartkouth-P8010:/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl$
```

And when I enter tclcl-1.20 and type "./configure" it shows an error too:

```
dartkouth@dartkouth-P8010:/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/tclcl$ sudo ./configure
No .configure file found in current directory
Continuing with default options...
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... yes
checking for dcgettext in -lintl... no
checking for getnodebyname in -ldnet_stub... no
checking that g++ can handle -O2... no
checking standard STL is available... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for strtoq... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking size of long... 4
checking for __int64_t... no
checking for long long... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking which kind of 64-bit int to use... int64_t
./configure: line 5926: tclsh: command not found
checking for tcl.h... -I../include
checking for tclInt.h... -I../include
checking for libtcl... no
checking for init.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5
checking for http.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5/http1.0
checking Tcl http.tcl library... yes
checking for tclsh... no
checking for tclsh... no
checking for tclsh... no
checking for tclsh8.4... no
configure: error: Installation of tcl seems incomplete or can't be found automatically.
Please correct the problem by telling configure where tcl is
using the argument --with-tcl=/path/to/package
(perhaps after installing it),
or the package is not required, disable it with --with-tcl=no.
dartkouth@dartkouth-P8010:/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/tclcl$
```

What can I do? I have already done "./configure + make" in the tcl folder.

Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ns all in one package no need to execute ./configure .just extract tar file and enter into all in one 2.35 folder type ./install. for Ubuntu u need to modify some of the source files in tclcl,tools refer the following link

http://erl1.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/installing-ns-2-34-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Answer (score 2):

Try using the flag ./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5 (or 8.4 in case you have 8.4 installed)... worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Change your current working directory to `/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/` (the folder in which ns is installed) and enter the following command in your terminal:

**Note: don't forget to change "dt" to your user name:**

```
./configure --with-tcl=/home/dt/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10 --with-tcl-ver=8.5.10  --with-tk=/home/dt/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10 --with-tk-ver=8.5.10
```