# Failure when checking tcl

Tags: http, tcl, configure, ns2

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and after adding some files for the integration of evalvid 2.7 and ns-2.35, i enter ./configure again from this directory:

> /home/user_name/Documents/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35

I got this error:

> checking Tcl http.tcl library... configure: error: Couldn't find http.tcl in /http /http2.5 /http2.4 /http2.3 /http2.1 /http2.0 /http1.0

Can someone help me fix this, thanks.

Comment: Since /http* does not have anything in front of it, it looks like some environment variable or other setting is not set.   I would check what options should be passed to configure first.

Comment: I found the answer. Here it is: `./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5`

Comment: Then write that up as an answer. Self-answers _are_ allowed, and encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5`

see [the post of @gbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277446/ns2-installation-error-on-ubuntu-12-10)